# Power Automate Expression - Parsing Text

Tags: office365, expression, power-automate

I have a Microsoft 365 Power Automate flow:

1. Take this HTML:

```
"Content": "<p><html><head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)\"><style>\r\n<!--\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Cambria Math\"}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:Calibri}\r\np.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\r\n\t{margin:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tfont-size:11.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif}\r\na:link, span.MsoHyperlink\r\n\t{color:#0563C1;\r\n\ttext-decoration:underline}\r\na:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed\r\n\t{color:#954F72;\r\n\ttext-decoration:underline}\r\np\r\n\t{margin-right:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-left:0cm;\r\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Times New Roman\",serif}\r\np.msonormal0, li.msonormal0, div.msonormal0\r\n\t{margin-right:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-left:0cm;\r\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Times New Roman\",serif}\r\nspan.EmailStyle19\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:windowtext}\r\nspan.EmailStyle20\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle21\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle22\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle23\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle24\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle25\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle26\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle27\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle28\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle29\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle30\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle31\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle32\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle33\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle34\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle35\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle36\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle37\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle38\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle39\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:windowtext}\r\nspan.EmailStyle40\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\nspan.EmailStyle42\r\n\t{font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D}\r\n.MsoChpDefault\r\n\t{font-size:10.0pt}\r\n@page WordSection1\r\n\t{margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt}\r\ndiv.WordSection1\r\n\t{}\r\n-->\r\n</style></head><body lang=\"EN-CA\" link=\"#0563C1\" vlink=\"#954F72\"><div class=\"WordSection1\"><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"background:#F7F9FA\"><b><span style=\"color:#3B3B3B\">Employee Name :</span></b><span style=\"color:#3B3B3B\">&nbsp;Clark Gable</span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"background:#F7F9FA\"><b><span style=\"color:#3B3B3B\">Job Title :</span></b><span style=\"color:#3B3B3B\">&nbsp;Agent, (Part-Time)</span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"background:#F7F9FA\"><b><span style=\"color:#3B3B3B\">Department :</span></b><span style=\"color:#3B3B3B\">&nbsp;Food Services</span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:#1F497D\ ETC ETC ETC
```

2. Turn to Text (output looks like this):

[image]

3. Add a row into an existing Excel table and add parsed text from step 2) into appropriate columns

To return the text **"Clark Gable"** into the table (for the **"Employee Name"** column), this is the expression I'm using, but it doesn't work:

```
first(skip(split(first(split(body('HTML_to_Text'),'Job Title ')),': '),1))
```

Does anyone know how to alter the expression to make it populate the Excel table correctly?

Comment: You've already asked this question, no?

Comment: Yes! The question got convoluted so I stated it (hopefully) a bit clearer here. The other question is deleted now!

Comment: If you want t help, include ALL of the HTML, don’t conclude it with etc etc etc